# ShinyApps: Error: 'parse_headers_list' is not an exported object from 'namespace:curl'

Tags: r, shinyapps

It's my first time using ShinyApps, and I'm having issues in the authorize account step. 
I got the code from the shinyapps page (of course I replaced the secret):

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='mytest',
          token='EFF0C8D7AB217F55D823D72162B61B1B',
          secret='<SECRET>')
```

And I got this message:

```
  Error: 'parse_headers_list' is not an exported object from 'namespace:curl'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It was a version problem. Just updated my R and R Studio and it worked